# Import org.eclipse.ui.wizard.datatransfer

Tags: java, eclipse, api, import

I need to create a Java program that it can import Java Projects, using the Eclipse API.  I know that I have to use the clase "ExternalProjectImportWizard" with the library org.eclipse.ui.wizard.datatransfer but when I try to import this library with the sentence

import org.eclipse.ui.wizard.datatransfer.*;

Eclipse don't know where it is and I don't know where I can download this library to add it in Eclipse.

How I can resolve this problem ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You already have this. It is part of the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin.

Note: you must be writing an Eclipse plugin to use this code, it will not work in a normal Java project.